# How to reduce the jar size of a codename one app to stay under 50meg

Tags: codenameone

My app is too large for the 50 meg limit so I am looking at some ways to significantly reduce the file size.

If I discard a dpi what happens when it runs on that dpi? I have some HUGE backgrounds making my app very bloated, I was wondering if I can remove them all but say the HD one and it would scale or would it be simply empty? Or would I need to change the background image scaling to make it do this?

Also CN1 seems to use png, can I use jpg for selected items to save space? Backgrounds that are 2.3 meg pngs could be 35k jpgs.. Even if I wrote a script that jpeged them after I press save in the gui designer, this could work I assume?

Any any further final tips for reducing the size of cn1 apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 50mb app is not only big, but prone to be slow on devices (performance wise).

To reduce your App size tremendously, do the following:

**All my answers are based on old GUI Builder**

- For background image, use a single image (not multi-image) and style the form UIID to use the image and type IMAGE_TO_FILL.
- Avoid using png image whenever possible, CN1 supports jpg perfectly.
- Don't use images for basic icons, use fonticon. Thousand of icons could be made 100kb and of high quality svg image that doesn't pixelate. I will explain at the end of this list how to create your custom fonticons.
- Avoid using 9-piece border image where it's not really needed, try to use solid background color if it won't ruin your design.
- Delete unused images, they also take a lot of space. On your GUI Builder.
- Re-use UIIDs, instead of creating multiple similar UIIDs.
- Migrate your GUI Builder forms to code, I posted a sample form Class to answer another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115419/how-to-pass-control-from-gui-created-form-to-code-created-form-in-codenameone) and also talk about similar thing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34153710/codename-one-separate-class-along-with-statemachine-class).
- Delete UIIDs you're not using and in most cases, copy and paste UUID of unselected style to selected, instead of creating similar.
- **Be Careful with this.** Keep your GUI Builder open, make sure **Xml team mode** is checked under **File**, save the GUI Builder after deleting Unused Images, without closing the GUI Builder, go to your project folder -> res -> delete theme.xml and the theme folder inside res folder (The name might be different if you've renamed your theme.res file). Now go back to your app and save again. A fresh copy of your res files would be saved in the same folder.
- Minimise the amount of background images you use, Modern good looking apps are simple plain background apps. E.g, Facebook, Twitter, Uber, AirBnB, BBC News App and many others. Unless your app is actually a game or necessarily require rich images that have to be static.
- Watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=set12jVQl_A) about performance tuning, It's a bit old but still contains useful information

If your app is bigger than 20 mb on iOS and 5mb on android, you should be worried about it's performance.

**Creating fonticons:**

1. Go to [fontello.com](http://fontello.com/) and check the icons present, if there are icons you need that are not there...
2. Go to [flaticon.com](http://www.flaticon.com/) and search for it there, download it as svg and drag'n'drop the svg on fontello webpage. If the icon doesn't look as expected...
3. Go back to flaticon.com and download the image as black 512px png image and go to [online-convert.com](http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-svg), convert the png to Monochrome svg file, this helps you to create a compound image that works well with fontello.
4. download the fonticon as zip on fontello and follow Shai's [chat app example](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/building-a-chat-app-with-codename-one-part-1.html) to use it. the zip contains demo html file to preview your icons and also a config.json that can be drag'n'drop on fontello.com to continue where you stopped.

Comment: Great answer! I'd also like to add that you can use the new material design icons now http://www.codenameone.com/blog/material-icons-background-music-geofencing-gradle.html if a suitable DPI isn't found when you do a get image on the resource, the closest DPI is picked. You can also detect the largest image in your resource file using the Images menu in the designer

Comment: Yes, great answer, my Jar has gone from 43 meg to 14 meg, I had actually forgotten that CN1 can use jpgs, and that you don't need to use a multi-image when you are using the scaling options. I used JDiskreport to seek out the big files, jpeg them, add them back as a normal image, and delete unused images each time.. Thanks, that was fun!